# Cannot download file by java - works in browser

Tags: java, http, url

I do currently something like this:

```
class FileDownloader{
    public static void downloadFile(URL myUrl, File myOutputFile) throws IOException{
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("UserAgent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11");
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myOutputFile));

    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int k = 0;
    while ((k = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        stream.write(buf, 0, k);
    }
    is.close();
    stream.close();
     }
 }
```

to download a file. But on some sites the download just doesnt work and i get forwarded to a Error page. When i open the exact same URL in Chrome or Firefox or even Internet Explorer it works.

Is there some RequestProperty i can set to get this thing to work? Or should i use another lib, like Apache HTTP?

Additional Information: I cannot look inside the Webserver Log nor can i adjust webservers settings.

Comment: *"something like this:"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). *"on some sites"* Provide some example URLs.

Comment: could you provide the url?

Comment: sorry, its not possible. these are internal services - so even if i would posts you the url your chances to connect to the server are very very low...

Comment: *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*

Comment: May be some URLs require authorization. While your browser has cookies, HttpURLConnection does not.

Comment: Add logging, for example with property `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and check http response status. Maybe it helps.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762030/download-file-with-original-file-name/15762288#15762288